# Facebook SSO for iOS7 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios7

i am having issue with facebook SSO. I am trying to do facebook SSO with the following method

```
-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
NSLog(@"inside openSessionWithAllowLoginUI");
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access,user_birthday,email,user_status", nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[permissions autorelease] allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {[ self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error]; }];
}
```

This opens up the active session successfully for iOS6 and earlier but not working for iOS 7.
If i am using openActiveSessionWithPermissions(this is depreciated) instead of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions (Which is the preferred method) in Facebook SSO then its working for iOS 7 as well. for example if i am using

```
-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
NSLog(@"inside openSessionWithAllowLoginUI");
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access,user_birthday,email,user_status", nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[permissions autorelease] allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {[ self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error]; }];
}
```

then its working. Its very confusing. Let me know if you need more information.
 Please help Guys.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No Errors just when i check the activeSession is open Or not using if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) then it says activeSession is not open. In iOs 6 it says connection is open.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Are you using the iOS integrated login, Facebook SSO, or webview? Can you add your sessionStateChanged:state:error: method as well? Also, the "offline_access" permission has been removed for over a year now, so that might be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i was using the older version of the facebook sdk. With the latest Version its working fine.

Special thanks to @Ming Li for the help.